# Create RMIServer during remote call

Tags: java, rmi

I have the following problem:

- Two nodes (A,B)
- A has an RMI client connected to B's RMI server
- A invokes a remote method on B
- During the invokation, B changes some variables and should create an RMI server

The problem is that I cannot create an RMI server during a remote call (fired by A which connects to B). The new RMI server should be created on B's localhost (otherwise I get an error: java.rmi.AccessException: Registry.Registry.rebind disallowed).

So what's the solution for that? I was thinking about something like scheduling a task on another thread that runs on B after that it receives the remote method invokation from A. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have misstated the problem. You *can* create an RMI server during a remote method call. Your problem is that you can't *bind* to a Registry running in a remote host.

This can only mean that it is your client which is doing the bind.

The solution is to have the new server bind itself, or have the remote method that creates it do so.